# Cast to (id) to call an arbitrary method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, performselector, respondstoselector

I have a situation when I need to call a method not necessarily supported by the object, but at the same time I can't use performSelector because it restricts the kind of arguments you can pass to the method. Hence I do this:

```
if ([someObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)])
    [(id)someObject someMethod];
```

The compiler is happy, I am happy, but are there any caveats with this method of message sending?

What is the essential difference between the synchronous version of performSelector and the above?

Edit: is there a performance penalty with performSelector compared to the (id) method?

Answer (score 7):

There are no special caveats here. By casting to `id` you are throwing away compiler-time checking, but you were doing that anyway with `performSelector:`.

Note that if you are using ARC the compiler will not let you do this unless it sees *some* implementation of `someMethod`.

Comment: I think it complained under non-ARC as well if there was no method implementation found anywhere.

Comment: @Gavin It warned under non-ARC, but you could laugh fiendishly and go ahead anyway. ARC, on the other hand, will stop you dead in your tracks; it's an error, not a warning.

Comment: Either way, it's still "complaining" :)

Comment: Actually, under non-ARC, it's just a little whining. Under ARC it's a full-out tantrum.

Comment: @Gavin I don't know why you're picking at this. What I said was "ARC ... will not let you". That is correct. Non-ARC _will_ let you.

Comment: I suspect there may be a slight performance penalty in case of performSelector compared to the (id) cast method.

Comment: @mojuba there's no difference between any of the methods of the `- (id)performToSelector:` family and a standard method call. They are exactly equivalent, so you won't notice any performance penalty.

Comment: I did think about the performance penalty when I wrote my answer. There is a performance penalty for calling `respondsToSelector:`, but the OP can't do without that call, so I didn't say anything about it.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella what's your statement based on? performSelector: has an extra level of indirection: it should lookup and call "performSelector" first and the the user's method, while with (id) it's just one lookup/call.

Comment: @mojuba they both boil down to `objc_msgSend` calls, that's why they are equivalent at runtime.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella with performSelector it boils down to (at least) two objc_msgSend() calls, while with (id) it's just one - the method you are calling.